# HashMap : Iterate & get the SUM of Values (Problem throw Itteration)

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to do a sum of the values contained in a Hashmap in order to calculte a turnover however the method seems to take into account only the last key/value.

Thanks for reading

Am I doing the iteration correctly ?

(I Do not want to use Stream)

```
   public double getMontantTotal() {

    double montantTotal = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<TypeDechet, Ligne> entry : lesLignes.entrySet()) {

        TypeDechet k = entry.getKey();
         Ligne v = entry.getValue();
       montantTotal = montantTotal+k.getPrixUnitare() * v.getNbSac();
    }

    return montantTotal;
}
```

Comment: It looks correct in my opinion.

Comment: can it be that your map somehow has only the last record that was inserted?

Comment: Hello, I've checked by doing a sysout,  the Hashmap contains 7 entry

Comment: Then you need to debug your program step by step to see why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,it was an error with the display ;)